# Inter service call between springboot micro services over OAuth2 secured API Gateway

Tags: oauth-2.0, microservices, api-gateway

Let's have simple system:

Service A: order-service
Service B: inventory-service

order service will call inventory, there is a OAuth2 secured API gateway and eureka server.

How order service call inventory service in a preferred way? Could I have a simple examples?

thanks!